# Tabs don't remember previous selections

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, unanswered-questions

I'm liking the updates to the site design except for one thing. Previously I am sure that I could select some options from the menus for filtering questions. Namely, *"Unanswered -> newest (tab)"* I could then answer/view a question and simply click the *"Unanswered"* item again and it would remember my previous selection of *newest*.

Doesn't seem like this is possible anymore, if I select "*Questions -> unanswered -> newest*" and go into a question then push the *"Questions"* button it just takes me back to all questions. I then have to select *"unanswered"* and *"newest"* again.

Am I doing something wrong in the new design? Is there a way to do what I want and I have missed it. (I realise I can click the back button, but old habits die hard)

## Update

By 'new' navigation I mean the one pictured below. The one that is currently available to all users as far as I am aware, not the one you have to opt in for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, its just not there...A developer will have to put a status or feature request to "cookie" this information out for you.

Comment: Which of the two navigations are you using? The new-new-new (?) navigation doesn't have "unanswered".

Comment: @Braiam I have updated with images to illustrate which menu I am talking about.

Comment: Perhaps this should be evaluated in the context of the new-nav development in course. I don't know if a feature-request on this aspect of the site could be taken in consideration now.

Comment: @Steve I didn't originally intend this to be a feature request as such, just that the old navigation had this feature which I found quite useful. It has been edited to a feature request. I originally thought it had been removed by mistake. If it has intentionally been removed, then why? If mistakenly removed, is that not something that indeed should be added to the new navigation.

Comment: I *think* the bit where unanswered forgets your sub-tab (newest, my tags, etc.) is fixed; can you confirm? That just leaves the top-level questions problem, which should be fixed by the new nav.

Comment: @Shog9 I can confirm it does seem to be fixed. Thanks.